# How to manually reset the footnote numbering in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context

I have a document with many footnotes, like this:

```
This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
This is some more text\footnote{This is another footnote}.
This is yet another text\footnote{This is some more footnote text}.
```

This produces footnotes numbered 1, 2, 3, etc.

I need to manually reset the footnote number back to 1. E.g.:

```
This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
This is some more text\footnote{This is another footnote}.
\resetfootnote
This is yet another text\footnote{This is some more footnote text}.
```

This should produce footnotes numbered 1, 2, then 1 again.

How can I manually reset the footnote counter?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes especially the section about *Footnote Numbering*?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing `way=bypage` and `way=bysection`, but it does not get the correct results, which is to have the numbers reset each time `\placefootnotes` is called. As `bypage` and `bysection` both don't do that, I need to be able to manually adjust the numbering.

Comment: Does the latex solution work in context? \setcounter{footnote}{0}

Comment: I found changing that solution to a ConTeXt-style syntax, `\setupcounter[footnote][0]` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\starttext

This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
This is some more text\footnote{This is another footnote}.
\resetcounter[footnote]
This is yet another text\footnote{This is some more footnote text}.

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

The **LaTeX** solution would be

```
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
```

In the comments we found out that this also works for **ConTeXt** after adapting the syntax:

```
\setupcounter[footnote][0]
```